# Show that there are exactly 4 homomorphisms from $ D_4 $ to $ Q_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, quaternions, dihedral-groups

I have a task where I need to show that there are exactly 4 homomorphisms from  $D_4 $ to $ Q_8 $.

I've been trying to use the fact that if $ \varphi: G \rightarrow H $ is a homomorphism, then $ |\varphi(g)|$  is dividing $|g|$.

However, It feels somewhat tedious to check what $\varphi$ can be and to check every single possibility. Is this how I'm supposed to do this?

Keep in mind that I still don't fully understand how to work with group theory, so I'm not really sure if I'm doing the right stuff at all.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $Q_8=\{\pm i, \pm j, \pm k , \pm 1\}$, $D_4$ is generated by a rotation $\rho$ of order $4$ and a reflection $r$ of order $2$, the defining relation $r\rho r=\rho^3$. So you want to see where $\rho, r$ can go under a homomorphism $\phi$.

The image of $r$ should have order $2$ or $1$. So it is either $-1$ or $1$. If the image of $r$ is $1$ then $\phi(\rho)=\phi(\rho^3)$, so $\phi(\rho)^2=1$, thus $\phi(\rho)$ is either $-1$ or $1$, we have two such homomorphisms.

Suppose that $\phi(r)=-1$. Then again $\phi(\rho^3)=\phi(r)\phi(\rho)\phi(r)=\phi(\rho)$ and, again,
$\phi(\rho)=\pm 1$ and we have two such homomorphisms, total of $4$.

Comment: I see. We have determined that there are 4 homomorphisms due to $D_4$ Being generated by $r$ and $ρ$, so we need only to check on them.

Comment: We need to check only that the image of $\rho$ has order dividing $4$, the image of $r$ has order dividing $2$ and the image or $r\rho r$ is the same as the image of $\rho$ cubed.

Comment: This is correct (some work may be needed to verify that all four choices yield an automorphism). It may be a little bit simpler to observe that $D_4$ is generated by two reflections: $r$ and $\rho r$. Both of those are order two, and hence need to be mapped to $\pm1$. Implying that all of $D_4$ gets mapped into the abelian subgroup $\{\pm 1\}\le Q_8$.